# how to import excel database to MSSQL 2000 retaining both database structure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have one database in Excel, with col. say A, B, C and D. Now, I want to import this database to MS SQL with already existing Table with structure uniqueID(Auto Incr.), A, B, C, D. How, can I import this data?

I am working in MS SQL 2000. I used custom Query Builder and  checked "Enabled identity insert". But still I am getting error with "Cannot insert null for uniqueID".. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this. Its possible, only if "Enabled identity insert" is unchecked.